# unary minus overload: member or non-member?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Given that prefix unary operators can be "*implemented by a non-static member function with no parameters or a non-member function with one parameter*" (§13.5.1[over.unary]/1), is there a difference besides the usual encapsulation/code reuse design rationales that apply to any member/non-member function choices?

For binary operators, [there's a semantic difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905439/overload-operators-as-member-operator-or-non-member-operator) because non-members allow implicit conversions of their left-hand operands. There doesn't seem to be anything like that for the unary operators, yet the standard defines `std::complex`'s unary negation operator as a non-member (§26.4.6[complex.ops]), while `std::valarray`'s and `std::duration`'s unary negation operators are members (§26.6.2.6[valarray.unary], §20.11.5.3[time.duration.arithmetic]). Is there a nuance?

Comment: When citing specific sections of the standard, you might want to mention which version you're referring to.

Comment: @André Caron Cited from the n3290 version of C++11, which is why I was able to bring up `duration`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there are no differences as compared to deciding if a non-operator function should be member or non-member. Obviously prefer non-member, non-friend when possible (like the standard algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

Using members when possible makes more sense, since you don't have to go crazy with friends. But otherwise, it is just a code style decision.

Comment: What about the Sutter/Alexandrescu new age guideline about making everything nonmember nonfriend if possible?

Comment: @Cubbi Yes it is always best to give the least possible access rights, but I prefer my code succinct.