# Function must have exactly one argument

Tags: c++, function

I've not coded in C++ for a long time and I'm trying to fix some old code.

I'm geting the error:

```
TOutputFile& TOutputFile::operator<<(TOutputFile&, T)' must have exactly one argument
```

on the following code:

```cpp
template<class T>
TOutputFile &operator<<(TOutputFile &OutFile, T& a);

class TOutputFile : public Tiofile{
public:
   TOutputFile (std::string AFileName);
   ~TOutputFile (void) {delete FFileID;}

   //close file
   void close (void) {
    if (isopened()) {
         FFileID->close();
         Tiofile::close();
      }
   }
   //open file
   void open  (void) {
      if (!isopened()) {
         FFileID->open(FFileName, std::ios::out);
         Tiofile::open();
      }
   }

   template<class T>
   TOutputFile &operator<<(TOutputFile &OutFile, const T a){
    *OutFile.FFileID<<a;
    return OutFile;
   }

protected:
   void writevalues  (Array<TSequence*> &Flds);
private:
   std::ofstream * FFileID;         


};
```

What's is wrong with that operator overloading ?

Comment: The function prototype should be after the class declaration/definition.

Comment: Your definition of the `operator<<()` is inside the class, which means it is a member.  As such, it has an implicit `this` parameter, in addition to the ones you have specified.   Move the definition outside the class.    (Then you're see other problems, but you haven't asked about those).

Comment: Making it a friend function will solve the issue, as it will no longer be a member function then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Overload operator<< as member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814345/cant-overload-operator-as-member-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

> The overloads of `operator>>` and `operator<<` that take a `std::istream&`
>   or `std::ostream&` as the left hand argument are known as insertion and
>   extraction operators. Since they take the user-defined type as the
>   right argument (b in a@b), **they must be implemented as non-members**.

Hence, they must be non-member functions, and take exactly two arguments when they are meant to be stream operators.

If you are developing your own stream class, you can overload `operator<<` with a single argument *as a member function*. In this case, the implementation would look something like this:

```
template<class T>
TOutputFile &operator<<(const T& a) {
  // do what needs to be done
  return *this; // note that `*this` is the TOutputFile object as the lefthand side of <<
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloaded functions which are defined as member functions accept only one parameter. In case of overloading `<<` operator, more than one parameter is required. Making it a `friend` function solves this issue.

```
class {
    ...
    friend TOutputFile &operator<<(TOutputFile &OutFile, const T &a);
    ...
};

template<class T>
TOutputFile &operator<<(TOutputFile &OutFile, const T &a) {
    *OutFile.FFileID << a;
    return OutFile;
}
```

A function marked as `friend` will allow that function to access private member of the class to which it is a friend.

Comment: Show the member variant, please. Also use `const T& a`.

Comment: I am not sure about what a member variant implies here.

Comment: Just another solution, towards which the error message OP's got is a direct guide.