# Function call for overloaded << operator (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

According to [Can't Overload operator<< as member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814345/cant-overload-operator-as-member-function)

> When overloaded as a member function, a << b is interpreted as
>   a.operator<<(b), so it only takes one explicit parameter (with this as
>   a hidden parameter).
>
> Since this requires that the overload be part of the class used as the
>   left-hand operand, it's not useful with normal ostreams and such. It
>   would require that your overload be part of the ostream class, not
>   part of your class. Since you're not allowed to modify ostream class,
>   you can't do that. That leaves only the global overload as an
>   alternative.

I know that for example:

`friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Obj &obj);`

acts like a function that takes an object of ostream and some object that you are trying to print and then returns an ostream object.

But I don't understand how doing `cout << obj` will call this function.

Wouldn't `cout << obj` do something like `cout.operator<<(obj)`, which is exactly what we don't want? So why does it actually call the function? And why does it allow the return value to go back to `cout`?

**EDIT:**

I had read over [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421715#4421715) previously and it states

> "A binary infix operator @, applied to the objects x and y, is called
>   either as operator@(x,y) or as x.operator@(y).4"

which provides some further clarity, but I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Basically `a << b` can mean `a.operator<<(b)` *or* `operator<<(a, b)`, so when you make a friend function `operator<<(cout, obj)` would be called. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421715/5754656) for more information.

Comment: @Artyer I see the part that says "A binary infix operator @, applied to the objects x and y, is called either as operator@(x,y) or as x.operator@(y).4" but i don't see how or where it's implied that "a << b can mean a.operator<<(b) or operator<<(a, b)"

Comment: @Artyer Answer in the answer section mate

Comment: @csguy It's not implied. It's directly stated. Literally by the quote you quoted.

Comment: regarding the edit: you don't see how "`x << y` is called as either `operator<<(x,y)` or [...]" answers your question of how `cout << obj` can find the function `operator<<(ostream&, const Obj&)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what the answer you quote says, although it doesn't do so very well.

An operator overload can be a member, or a non-member.

For example, `anOstream << aT` can be resolved with a `ostream& ostream::operator<<(T)` (or similar) or with a free function `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, T)`. Either of those can be called. That's just how it is. That's what the standard says.

Since we can't add things to `ostream`, the latter is how we go about it (though, for your own types, it would be pretty much up to you).

Notice how I chose a return type of `ostream&` for those examples; that's how "the return value goes back to `cout`": the left-hand operand is simply returned back by reference.

Comment: oh i guess i didn't understand it. so when you do cout << obj, it's something like cout << function(ostream, obj);

Comment: @csguy `std::cout << obj` calls `operator<<(std::cout, obj)` if there is no `std::ostream::operator<<` member that can take the `obj` as input. `std::cout` is an object instance of type `std::ostream`, so it can be passed as-is to a `std::ostream&` parameter, thus satisfying the call to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const decltype(obj) &)`.

Comment: @csguy Sort of yeah

Answer (score 2):

The compiler would call cout.operator<<(obj) if it was present but if it isn't it will look for a compatible global function.

e.g. Below it will call the member function. But if that is commented out it will call the global function.

```
#include <iostream>
class Ostr;

class Obj {
    public:
    void print(Ostr& os) const;
};
class Ostr {
    public:
    Ostr& operator<<(const Obj& obj){
        std::cout << "member";
        obj.print(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    Ostr& operator<<(const char* obj){
        std::cout << obj;
        return *this;
    }
};
void Obj::print(Ostr& os) const {
    os << "Obj";
}

template<class T>
auto operator<<(Ostr& os, const T& t) -> decltype(t.print(os), os) { 
    os << "global";
    t.print(os); 
    return os; 
} 

int main() {
    Obj obj;
    Ostr ostr;
    ostr << obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's good phrasing