# Friend functions and their relationship to the I/O Operators

Tags: c++, function, io, overloading, friend

I've pored over information regarding friend functions and their use. They're able to access encapsulated data within a class while not breaking one of the golden rules of OOP. In purveying various source code for overloading the I/O operators (A basic operation, one of the first taught in learning C++) every one defines the operator as a friend as implements it outside of the class. My question is: does this *need* to be done? Why not just declare the function as a public member of the class and insert/display data from the class while keeping everything encapsulated? It seems no different than overloading other operators, yet it is a supposedly traditional approach to overloading the I/O operators.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overload operators as member function or non-member (friend) function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905439/overload-operators-as-member-function-or-non-member-friend-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to overload `operator<<` for your class `X`, so you can use it like this:

```
X x;
std::cout << x;
```

Notice that `std::cout` is the first operand of the operator. To implement this as a member function, it would have to be a member of `std::basic_ostream`, which is the type of `std::cout`. You can't add members to an already defined class. That's why we declare it as a free function instead.

If you overloaded `operator<<` as a member of `X`, it would be taking an `X` object as its first operand, so you would use it like this:

```
X x;
x << something;
```

This is obviously not what you want when dealing with I/O.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an overloaded operator like: `a @ b` implemented as a member function, that call is translated to `a.operator@(b);`. That means the function must be a member of the class that's the type of the *left* operand. In the case of iostreams, that would be all the operators needed to be members of the iostream itself.

While iostreams do provide *some* insertion/extraction operators as members, you normally want to be able to add more *without* modifying the iostream class itself<sup>1</sup>. To do that, you pretty much need to implement the operator as a free function instead of a member function. Since you normally still want it to have access to the private parts of whatever type you're planning to read/write (insert/extract, if you prefer) it typically has to be a friend of that class.

---

1. This is an example of the so-called open/closed principle: the class should be open to extension, but closed to modification. In other words, you want to extend it without modifying it.