# How to choose which operator overload in C++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm learning C++ and creating a simple class, `tstring`, defined by:

- `n` the number of characters in a string;
- `ntotal` the total number of characters in the tstring;
- `p`, pointer to a zone which contains the data.

Hence, this class is composed by a static part (`n`, `ntotal` and `p`) and by a dynamic part (the data itself).

I created three constructors :

- one without parameters;
- one copy constructor;
- one constructor which takes a C-string parameter.

I would like to be able to concatenate one `tstring` object with one C string, using for example the instructions :

```
tstring x("Hello), y;
y = x + " World";
```

I think I should overload the `+` operator. However I don't understand which way I should use to overload it between internal way :

```
tstring tstring::operator+(char string[])
```

or external way (with setter and getter methods)

```
tstring operator+ (const tstring& myTstring, const char* string)
```

Can someone explain me the difference and the best way to adopt?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overload operators as member function or non-member (friend) function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905439/overload-operators-as-member-function-or-non-member-friend-function)

Comment: For something like this, I would use "tstring tstring::operator+(char string[])" because you want access to the member variables without having to friend the operator function from the class.

Comment: @thang I disagree, the issue is with calling `char[]` + `tstring`, won't work in this case (even if `char[]` is implicitly convertible to `tstring`, it won't be converted as it appears on the left hand side). I think it's a good rule of thumb to declare the binary operators as friends.

Comment: @vsoftco, but "tstring operator+ (const tstring& myTstring, const char* string)" won't solve that problem, but now you have to add that operator+ function as a friend.

Comment: What I'd do is declare an implicit constructor that converts `char[]` to `tstring`, i.e. `tstring::tstring(char[])`, then simply define `operator+(tstring, tstring)` as a friend. There's nothing wrong with having it as a friend, it doesn't break encapsulation more than the member function, and it definitely makes life a bit easier.

Comment: @vsoftco, that works, too, but the constructor probably does a new and a memcpy (and subsequently delete in the destructor).  now you're copying the initial portion twice.  once in the constructor and once when + happens.  consider this code:  tstring x = "";  for (int i  = 0; i < 1000; i++) { x = "hello " + x; } (or something to that effect)

Comment: @thang well yes, if one cares so much about efficiency, one can declare a move constructor, so the rvalue `tstring(char[])` is moved ;)

Comment: @vsoftco, how does that solve the current problem?  move constructor won't remove the memcpy from string literal into a temporary memory before +.

Comment: @thang define `operator+(tstring&&, tstring&&)`, I didn't go in more details, but overall it's a matter of preference. In general though, when one doesn't deal with this kind of resource acquisition situation, I still thing the `friend` approach is the way to go. Maybe I should give this problem a try, as it seems a nice exercise :)

Comment: @vsoftco, still doesn't remove the literal to tstring conversion.  an advantage of having a separate operator+ for const char* as in esesen's answer is that the literal on the lhs gets copied only once.

Comment: @thang, yes, I agree here, you're right. For string literals you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you probably should consider concatenation of two `tstring`s first.  Having this, you may decide to allow your `tstring(const char *)` constructor to deal with conversion for you. This way you will get concatenation with C-strings free.

Then you'll notice that `tstring` + `char []` does not yield the same result as `char []` + `tstring`.  That is because first will call your converting constructor and second will not find any matching operator.

As having asymmetrical `operator+` is counterintuitive, you should also provide non-member `operator+(const char *, tstring const &)` that will forward its arguments to its in-class sibling.

Comment: again a matter of preference, but I'd just declare one `friend operator+(tstring, tstring)`, and with the implicit constructor everything will just work.